# angular disable buttton after first click and then enable after page refresh

Tags: angular

I have the following code in my HTML File:

```
  <div class="col-md-2">
        <button *ngIf="!FinishingVerification" class="appBtn lineButton" (click)="FinishVerification(); clicked = true;" [disabled]="clicked"   >
          Finish {{Caption}}
          <span><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>
        </button>
        <i *ngIf="FinishingVerification" class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"    ></i>
      </div>
```

In my component, I have a boolean variable clicked.

```
public clicked: boolean=false;
```

Inside the FinishVerification(). I am setting

```
this.clicked = false;
```

I want to make the button enabled again when the page reloads or user revisits the page in the same session without exiting the application.

How can I do that?

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that "AngularJS" only refers to the 1.X versions of the framework. Your code uses Angular 2+ syntax, so I've fixed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import and implement ngOnInit in your component.ts

```
class Component implements OnInit {

    public clicked: boolean;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.clicked = false;
     }
// your code 
}
```

After reload, it will gain the same value stated in the ngOnInit.

Edit1:

You need to add NgOnDestroy() so the code is:

```
class Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

        public clicked: boolean;

        ngOnInit() {
            this.clicked = false;
         }
    // your code

ngOnDestroy() {
       this.clicked = false; }  
    }
```

This will cause that when you leave the page or that route, will automatically change the value of your variable, so when you return, clicked is going to bw false and therefore available to be clicked again.

Comment: I did exactly what you told me and it works when the page reloads, but when I switch between the pages or revisit the page then the breakpoint does not go to ngOnInit()

Comment: I put refresh in the subject line. In the question, I mentioned to enable the button if I revisit the page.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a shared service to persist the state of the variable. Use it in all the components you want to use the variable.

Example code:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataServiceService } from './data-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private dataService: DataServiceService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.dataService.getGlobalValue() === undefined) {
      this.dataService.setGlobalValue(false);
    }
  }

  clicked() {
    console.log(this.dataService.getGlobalValue());
    this.dataService.setGlobalValue(!this.dataService.getGlobalValue());
  }

}
```

**data-service.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataServiceService {

  _globalValue: any;

  constructor() { }

  getGlobalValue(): any {
    return this._globalValue;
  }

  setGlobalValue(value: any) {
    this._globalValue = value;
  }

}
```

Complete code on Stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xloiz8